# C# - Como imprimir todos os valores de um array com o comando Console.WriteLine(???);?

Tags: c#, array

//Fazer a copia de um array e imprimir os 2.

```
        int[] original = new int[] { 2, 5, 3, 8, 9, 12, 15, 7 };
        int[] copia = new int[original.Length];

        for (int index = 0; index < original.Length; index++)
        {
            copia[index] = original[index];


        }
        Console.WriteLine(); //o que eu colo para mostrar todos os valores de um dos arrays?
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", copia));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem algumas opções, segue algumas

```
int[] original = new int[] { 2, 5, 3, 8, 9, 12, 15, 7 };
int[] copia = new int[original.Length];

for (int index = 0; index < original.Length; index++) copia[index] = original[index];

Console.WriteLine("Original 1");
original.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));

Console.WriteLine("Copia 1");
copia.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));

Console.WriteLine("Original 2");
original.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

Console.WriteLine("Copia 2");
copia.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

Console.WriteLine("Original 3");
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", original));

Console.WriteLine("Copia 3");
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", copia));

Console.WriteLine("Original 4");
foreach (var item in original) Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

Console.WriteLine("Copia 4");
foreach (var item in copia) Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
```

<sub>Baseado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16265268/6200920) do SO</sub>